# HTTP request error from running Postman Collection tests with Newman?

Tags: json, postman

I've been using the new commandline for Postman, [Newman](http://www.getpostman.com/docs/newman_intro), and have been attempting to run Collection tests that work fine when I pass them through the packaged app Jetpacks add-on, but do not run properly in the commandline. Although the json Collection file that I am passing does contain the proper header declarations, I don't have any other clues at this point, so I suspect that this may be an HTTP header issue. But I am not sure exactly what is wrong, as I am rather new to using Postman.

The tests that I'm trying to run are on some calls to an ASP.Net web API, very simple server response-checking one-line javascript tests like the ones [in this tutorial](http://blog.getpostman.com/index.php/2014/03/07/writing-automated-tests-for-apis-using-postman/).

A sample line that I enter into the console:

```
$ newman -c collectionfile.json -e environmentfile.json -n 5
```

achieves such a result:

```
RequestError: [token] terminated. Error: undefined
```

Any suggestions/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this problem as well and spent quite a few hours trying to figure it out. Eventually I realized that an address such as "www.google.com" will work in the chrome plugin UI, but not in Newman. For it to work in Newman, the address must be "https://www.google.com". Also, make sure that you have your data file (if you are using variables like {{url}}) set up correctly. You can use "-d dataFile.json" to define a data file. More information on that [here](http://www.getpostman.com/docs/newman_intro).